# How to measure data completeness in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas and I have a dataset containing 20 columns and 65 rows. What I'm trying to do is to try to measure the data completeness. So, I want to check the percentage of NaN values compared to the whole dataset. For example, the output I need is: **The percentage of NaNs in the dataset is: 40%**

I've counted the number of NaNs by doing the following:  `comp_df.isna().sum().sum()` and got a result of **776**. But, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
comp_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[np.nan,1,1], 
                            b=[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]))
print (comp_df)
     a   b
0  NaN NaN
1  1.0 NaN
2  1.0 NaN
```

In your solution is possible divide by [`DataFrame.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) for number of all values:

```
print (comp_df.isna().sum().sum() / comp_df.size * 100)
66.66666666666666
```

Or reshape values to `Series`, by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and use `mean`, what is `sum/count` by definition:

```
print (comp_df.isna().stack().mean() * 100)
66.66666666666666
```